# (C) Trouble with adding integers

Tags: c

I'm having troubles with a simple addition calculator.

After I put in the first number, the program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Addition calculator\n");
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf(" %d",num1);
    printf("\nEnter the second number: ");
    scanf(" %d",num2);
    int sol;
    sol=num1+num2;
    printf("The solution is %d", sol);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue that is troubling you?

Comment: `scanf(" %d",&num1);`, `scanf(" %d",&num2);`. Enable warnings on your compiler.

Comment: @remyabel the op had it, I do no know why the op changed it?

Comment: @kick buttowski, when I run it, after putting in the first number it says "calculator.exe has stopped working"

Comment: did you correct what @remyabel told you

Comment: @remyable hmmm. I was under the impression you only put the "&" in front when you're looking for only a single character/number. Guess not. It works

Comment: @Jeremy did not you have &s at begining and you removed them?

Comment: Here's an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c69c6f5fb1833bf) of the kinds of warnings you get when enabled.

Comment: @remyable, nope. Instead, I had warnings saying "format argument is not a pointer."

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf(" %d", &num1);
```

`scanf` expects an address of a variable, so it can change its value. You're passing in the *value* of `num1` as an address, which has a very very *very* high probability to be somewhere your program is not allowed to write.

Same for `num2`.

I love analogies, so...

Think about this code:

```
int recordASeven(int x) {
  x = 7;
}
int main() {
  int y = 0;
  recordASeven(y);
  printf("y is %d\n", y);
}
```

This prints `0`. Why? It's like this: You have a piece of paper in your locker, with "0" written on it. You copy the "0" carefully onto another piece of paper, give it to a friend and say "write down 7 here instead". He does so, then throws paper away. You look into your locker, and there's your own paper with "0" on it. Because you're passing your friend a copy of your paper and not your own paper, he can't change your own original. Same with functions in C - they can't ever change the variables they get passed in. So `scanf` can't ever modify the variables directly.

```
int recordASevenBetter(int *x) {
  *x = 7;
}
int main() {
  int y = 0;
  recordASeven(&y);
  printf("y is %d\n", y);
}
```

Now here you take a blank piece of paper, give him the combination that will open your locker, and give *that* to your friend, saying "go to my locker, write down 7 on the paper in there". When you go and inspect the paper in your locker later, sure enough, there's "7" on it. In C speak, "&y" will give you the location of where the value of `y` is ("pointer"), so that anything can change it; "*x" will access the value in the location specified by the value of `x`.

```
int recordASevenAndFailMiserably(int *x) {
  *x = 7;
}
int main() {
  int y = 0;
  recordASeven(y);
  printf("y is %d\n", y);
}
```

Finally, here's your problem: you give your friend a copy of your "0", and tell him it's your locker combination. When he goes to open your locker, he gets frustrated, trashes your room and pees on the floor.

In this case, the compiler can detect the disparity, since there is a clear mismatch between the declared and the provided types, and the compiler will refuse to do it. But `scanf` uses variadic argument list, which means the declaration does not list the parameter types. It will be the responsibility of `scanf` to decypher the format and interpret the bag of bytes it gets as something sensible. And the compiler can only stand by and watch shaking its head (when you enable warnings) as you lie to `scanf` about what you're giving it.

Comment: More like "You are passing in `num1` itself instead...". He is not converting it to a pointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: He isn't. Compiler is. There is not much difference between a pointer and an integer - you can cast one into the other very easily, and in fact compiler does it "for you" in this case.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't heard of this "address" thing yet. Thank You.

Comment: The compiler also does not convert here. `scanf` later proceeds on the mistaken assumption that it has a first variadic argument of type `int`, but that's got nothing to do with conversion. (There can be any arbitrary ID-mapping beween pointers and integers, `int` and `void*`, need not even have the same size.)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Vice versa: it believes the first variadic argument is an `int *`, and proceeds accordingly. See remyabel's link. There is no conversion, since the content does not change, but that content is interpreted in different ways. As you point out, on architectures where the sizeof of ints and pointers differs, the fail is even more painful, as wrong number of bytes will be taken off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please change it to &num1 and &num2 as mentioned by Amandan. You have to pass the address of the variable.

Comment: This is pretty much repeating @Amadan's answer.

Comment: It's because i cannot upvote. My points are less.